# Tiling raster from QGIS 3.18

Tags: qgis, raster, geoserver, tiles

I have some large tif raster that I want to use the ImageMosaic feature on Geoserver to serve.  I am viewing them in QGIS and have been through every plugin, tool and saveas VRT option I can find but end up with weird and differing results every time, none of which really serve the purpose.  I need to cut up my images into about 100m x 100m tiles at full resolution and then create a shp index feature for import into Geoserver.  This should be so simple.  What am I missing?  It seems the QGIS tools in past versions were simple and direct but now I can't seem to find a GDAL solution or any other!

Comment: have you considered using [gdal_retile,py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_retile.html)

Comment: Ian I have tried them all.  GDAL_retile seems to work but it runs forever creating images most of which have nothing in them!  What image compression profile is most bombproof?  Any other parameters I am not setting properly?  I am using mostly defaults except for the tile size and the write directory.

Comment: You do not need to do what you are trying to do. Just save the whole image as a tiled GeoTIFF, create the overviews, and publish with GeoServer.

Comment: Is a tiled GeoTIFF not a bunch of GeoTIFF tiles?  I am missing the distinction here.  What creation procedure are you suggesting?

Comment: 100m tiles sound very small (unless you have sub cm resolution data) - I would usually use a tile size of 512 or 1024 with `gdal_retile` - Alternatively you should look at http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html Can you add more details about your raster